# Unable to use Culebra

Tags: android, windows, python-2.7, androidviewclient

I am on Windows 8 with python 2.7.9 and androidviewclient-10.5.1 installed.
I extracted AndroidViewClient-master.zip to C drive, after that I installed android viewclient using easy_install
I can find Culebra inside following directories:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-10.5.1-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts

C:\Python27\Scripts

C:\AndroidViewClient-master\tools
```

The file size is 41.1 KB and it is without any extension. It is a python script as I can open it in notepad and see, but without any extension.

When I am statring cmd at those places and trying to run culebra --help or any culebra command, I am getting the error as

```
C:\AndroidViewClient-master\tools>culebra -G
'culebra' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\AndroidViewClient-master\tools>
```

PATH variabale is as below:

```
C:\Android SDK\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\AndroidViewClient-master\src;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-10.5.1-py2.7.egg;C:\Android SDK\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\platform-tools
```

What wrong I am doing here?
Is there anything am I missing? I am clueless.
Do I need to configure/install something else in order to use Culebra? How?
How to start Culebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am on Windows 8 with python 2.7.9 and androidviewclient-10.5.1
>   installed. I extracted AndroidViewClient-master.zip to C drive

It's one or the other, if you have installed `androidviewclient-10.5.1` (using easy_install on Windows as described in https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#microsoft-windows) then there's no need to extract any zip.

Windows does not support [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) so I think you should do

```
C:\AndroidViewClient-master\tools>python culebra -G
```

Comment: first I did AVC installed using esay_install only but it did not work, then I extracted the zip to make it work.